# Exporting function symbols from symtab to dynsym

Tags: reverse-engineering, elf, debug-symbols

My goal is to make symbols visible for `dlsym` for futher use.

Currently all symbols are in the `.symtab`

I tried using `LIEF` to export them, but always got `Exec format error` after modification

my elf file:
`ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`

As far as I know symbols have to be located in dynamic table to be accessible using `dlsym` but haven't found anything which could do that.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know symbols have to be located in dynamic table to be accessible using dlsym

Correct.

> but haven't found anything which could do that.

Rebuilding the dynamic symbol table such that it includes new symbols is *very* involved (you need to rebuild the `.hash` or `.gnu.hash` as well), so I am not surprised you can't find any tools which reliably do that.

You probably should look for another method of achieving whatever it is you are trying to achieve (see also [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)).

Answer (score 1):

You can supply the linker with the [`--export-dynamic`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002dE) flag to achieve exactly what you are looking for.